# Creating a timer that shows the time in hh:mm:ss format JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, timer

===================================================

**Edit**

Thanks to [Sedrick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2423906/sedrick) help, I progressed.

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override // Override the start method in the Application class
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        FakeCustomNode clockNode = new FakeCustomNode(180);
        Scene scene = new Scene(clockNode, 300, 300);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Timer"); // Set the stage title
        primaryStage.setScene(scene); // Place the scene in the stage
        primaryStage.show(); // Display the stage
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
    }

    /**
     * The main method is only needed for the IDE with limited JavaFX support. Not
     * needed for running from the command line.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

=======================================================================

```
final public class FakeCustomNode extends VBox {

    TimerGUI stopWatchGUI;

    public FakeCustomNode(int minutes) {
        stopWatchGUI = new TimerGUI(minutes);
        getChildren().addAll(stopWatchGUI.getStopWatch());
    }
}
```

====================================================================

```
public class TimerGUI {
    Text display;
    Button start;
    Button pause;
    Button reset;
    VBox vbox = new VBox();

    int second;

public class TimerGUI {
    Text display;
    VBox vbox = new VBox();
    int second;

    public TimerGUI(int time) {
        this.second = time * 60;
        display = new Text(String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", second / 3600, (second % 3600) / 60, second % 60));

        Timeline stopWatchTimeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1), (ActionEvent event) -> {
            if (second-- > 0)
                display.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", second / 3600, (second % 3600) / 60, second % 60));
        }));
        stopWatchTimeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        stopWatchTimeline.play();

        vbox.getChildren().addAll(display);
    }

    public VBox getStopWatch() {
        return vbox;
    }
}
```

I don't understand how to change the code so the timer will start on specific action.
At the moment I ran it, the timer starts.

I want to show `03:00:00` and after specific action the timer will start.

How can I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Get some ideas from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50626831/how-to-set-up-two-timelines-to-one-app/50627639#50627639).

Comment: @Sedrick I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

When you say ***"specific action"***, I am assuming you mean something like a button press. In the linked code the TimerGUI has three buttons associated with it. <kbd>Start</kbd>, <kbd>Pause</kbd>, and <kbd>Reset</kbd>. Use those to handle different situations. The code below demos those buttons.

> TimerGUI Class

```
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class TimerGUI {
    Text display;
    Button start;
    Button pause;
    Button reset;
    VBox vbox = new VBox();

    int second;

    public TimerGUI(int minutes) {
        this.second = minutes * 60;
        display = new Text(String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", second / 3600, (second % 3600) / 60, second % 60));
        // display = new Text();
        start = new Button("Start");        
        pause = new Button("Pause");
        reset = new Button("Stop");
        
        Timeline stopWatchTimeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1), (ActionEvent event) -> {
            second--;
            display.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", second / 3600, (second % 3600) / 60, second % 60));
        }));
        stopWatchTimeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        
        start.setOnAction((event) -> {
            stopWatchTimeline.play();
        });
        pause.setOnAction((event) -> {
            stopWatchTimeline.pause();
        });
        reset.setOnAction((event) -> {
            stopWatchTimeline.stop();
            this.second = minutes * 60;
            display.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", second / 3600, (second % 3600) / 60, second % 60));
        });

        vbox.getChildren().addAll(display, new HBox(start, pause, reset));
    }

    public VBox getStopWatch() {
        return vbox;
    }
    
    
    public void setTimer(int minutes)
    {
        this.second = minutes * 60;
        display = new Text(String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", second / 3600, (second % 3600) / 60, second % 60));
    }
}
```