# How to redraw line position without stopping program

Tags: java, javafx

I want to create seconds arrow with `Line` object. On button click arrow should start spinning in a circle in other `Thread`. The program not responding while calculating current rotate position. How to do this correctly?
FXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.Line?>

<Pane fx:id="rootPane" focusTraversable="true" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" onKeyPressed="#startSecondsLine" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
    <children>
        <Line fx:id="secondsLine" endX="60.0" layoutX="300.0" layoutY="200.0" startX="-100.0" strokeWidth="2.0" />
      <Label layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" text="Start(X, Y):" />
      <Label layoutX="14.0" layoutY="31.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="63.0" text="End(X, Y):" />
      <Label fx:id="startXY" layoutX="77.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="63.0" />
      <Label fx:id="endXY" layoutX="77.0" layoutY="31.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="63.0" />
      <Button layoutX="15.0" layoutY="48.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#startTimer" text="Start" />
    </children>
</Pane>
```

Controller:

```
package sample;

import java.net.URL;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;

public class Controller {
    @FXML
    private Line secondsLine;

    @FXML
    private Label startXY;

    @FXML
    private Label endXY;

    @FXML
    void startTimer(ActionEvent event) {
        MyThread myThread = new MyThread(secondsLine);
        myThread.run();
    }

    @FXML
    void initialize() {
        startXY.setText("(" + secondsLine.getStartX() + ", " + secondsLine.getStartY() + ")");
        endXY.setText("(" + secondsLine.getEndX() + ", " + secondsLine.getEndY() + ")");
    }
}
```

`MyThread class`

```
package sample;

import javafx.scene.shape.Line;

public class MyThread extends Thread {
    private Line line;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(line + " from other thread.");
        try {
            rotateLine();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public MyThread(Line line) {
        this.line = line;
    }

    public void rotateLine() throws InterruptedException {
        int circle = 0;
        System.out.println("Start of circle;");
        do {
            sleep(1000);
            line.setRotate(circle);
            circle += 6;
        } while (circle < 360);
        System.out.println("End of circle;");
    }
}
```

Comment: The blocking is explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674174/what-is-the-difference-between-thread-start-and-thread-run However you must not update the gui from a background thread so even replacing `run` with `start` the implementation is incorrect. See the following question for an example of doing it properly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9966136/javafx-periodic-background-task

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59442763/javafx-group-contents-position-getting-changed-upon-transformation

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50626831/how-to-set-up-two-timelines-to-one-app/50627639#50627639

Comment: I should use `TimeLine` animation instead of thread?

Comment: yes, see this [example](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/3388637)