# JavaFX: How to stop Timeline countdown timer when zero is reached

Tags: java, javafx

I have this code that displays count down from 10 downward:

[image]

However it continues counting into negative numbers after zero is reached. How do I stop it after zero is reached? So that the last text to be displayed on the label is `0`.

```
import javafx.animation.Animation;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class TestCountdown extends Application {
    private GridPane gridPane;
    private Scene scene;

    private Button button = new Button("Start");
    private CountdownTimer timer = new CountdownTimer();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage applicationStage) {
        gridPane = new GridPane();
        scene = new Scene(gridPane);

        gridPane.add(timer, 0, 1);
        gridPane.add(button, 0, 2);

        timer.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 50;");
        button.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 50;");

        button.setOnAction(actionEvent -> timer.start());

        applicationStage.setScene(scene);
        applicationStage.setFullScreen(true);
        applicationStage.show();
    }
}

class CountdownTimer extends Label {
    private int i = 10;

    private boolean started;

    public CountdownTimer() {
        setText("10");
    }

    public void start() {
        if (started)  {
            return;
        }

        Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(0),
                event -> {
                    setText(String.valueOf(i--));

                    if (i <= 0)  {
                        timeline.stop(); //ERROR: variable timeline might not have been initialized
                    }
                }),
                new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1)));

        timeline.setOnFinished(event -> System.out.println("Done!"));
        timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
        timeline.play();
 
        started = true;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**:

[image]

**EDIT**: Code above is updated:

```
 if (i <= 0)  {
                        timeline.stop(); //ERROR: variable timeline might not have been initialized
                    }
```

if-block gives

```
ERROR: variable timeline might not have been initialized
```

error

Comment: timeline.stop ..?

Comment: @kleopatra Doesn't work. See edit

Comment: your if block still is empty

Comment: @kleopatra ? it's not. See screenshot

Comment: no screenshots of text .. provide a [mcve] and keep it current..

Comment: @kleopatra  I have provided it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to set up two timelines to one app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50626831/how-to-set-up-two-timelines-to-one-app)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of adding in constructor, try adding KeyFrames after Timeline is initialized.

```
Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
KeyFrame kf = new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(0),
        event -> {
            setText(String.valueOf(i--));
            if (i <= 0) {
                timeline.stop();
            }
        });
timeline.getKeyFrames().addAll(kf, new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1)));
```