# JavaFX countdown using timeline and displaying as a label

Tags: java, javafx, label, timeline, keyframe

I need to create a countdown in the hh:mm:ss format that updates every second and displays this to the user through the use of a label however I am unsure how to do this. When the timeline hits zero an action should also be taken.

Comment: See if the `StopWatchGUI` class from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50626831/how-to-set-up-two-timelines-to-one-app/50627639#50627639) can help you get started.

Comment: @Sedrick would this work for counting down though?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one example for a count down with the use of `TimeLine`:

```java
package org.example;

import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

public class CountDownExampleApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        // Create label to display the time left:
        Label countDownLabel = new Label();

        // Create duration property for time remaining:
        ObjectProperty<java.time.Duration> remainingDuration
                = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(java.time.Duration.ofSeconds(5)); // Here: 5 sec count down

        // Binding with media time format (hh:mm:ss):
        countDownLabel.textProperty().bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(() ->
                        String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d",
                                remainingDuration.get().toHours(),
                                remainingDuration.get().toMinutesPart(),
                                remainingDuration.get().toSecondsPart()),
                remainingDuration));

        // Create time line to lower remaining duration every second:
        Timeline countDownTimeLine = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1), (ActionEvent event) ->
                remainingDuration.setValue(remainingDuration.get().minus(1, ChronoUnit.SECONDS))));

        // Set number of cycles (remaining duration in seconds):
        countDownTimeLine.setCycleCount((int) remainingDuration.get().getSeconds());

        // Show alert when time is up:
        countDownTimeLine.setOnFinished(event -> new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION).show());

        // Prepare and show stage:
        stage.setScene(new Scene(new Pane(countDownLabel), 200, 100));
        stage.show();

        // Start the time line:
        countDownTimeLine.play();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting errors with the bindings and im assuming thats because im running java 8