# Modify JavaFX TextArea with a Thread other than "JavaFX Application Thread" and "Main"

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

My problem is that I have a JavaFX TextArea and want to update its contents in a separate thread to show new text instantly instead of a bunch after the method has finished.
Say, for example, I wanted to build a timer. In the current case, the TextArea would show 10 at the beginning, then I would press the "Start" button, wait ten seconds and a zero shows up. If this works multithreaded, it would count down from ten to zero with all the numbers in between.

Here's a sample code:

```
TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
Button button = new Button("Start");
GridPane root = new GridPane();
root.add(textArea);
root.add(button);

button.setOnMouseClicked((event) -> {
   new Thread(() -> {
      for (int i = 10; i >= 0; i--) {
         textArea.setText(Integer.parseInt(i));
         try { Thread.sleep(1000); }
         catch (InterruptedException ie) { ie.printStackTrace(); }
      }
   }).start();
});
```

This code ends in an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` in the `FX Application Thread` for me, which only shows up when the `setOnMouseClicked` event is executed in another thread.
It works for both the "FX Application Thread" and the "Main" thread.

Comment: See if something from the `Animation` API like `Timeline` or `AnimationTimer` can help

Comment: So, that code should fail to compile, as `parseInt` returns an `int`, and `setText` expects a `String`. But I'll assume that's a mistake only in your question and in your real code you actually use something like `Integer.toString(i)`. Now, a quick fix for your code would be to use `String text = Integer.toString(i); Platform.runLater(() -> textArea.setText(text));`. However, using background threads for something like this is overkill and makes everything harder. You should do as SedJ601 suggests and use an animation.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/60685975/6395627 for some more information.

Comment: [JavaFX countdown using timeline and displaying as a label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67578178/javafx-countdown-using-timeline-and-displaying-as-a-label)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50626831/how-to-set-up-two-timelines-to-one-app/50627639#50627639

Comment: Understand that JavaFX is, by design, single threaded, **you must not**: *Modify JavaFX TextArea with a Thread other than "JavaFX Application Thread"*.  Techniques suggested in comments, don't actually modify the node from another thread at all.  All animation events and timeline events occur only on the JavaFX thread.   `runLater` calls schedule the thing to run later on the JavaFX application thread.  [Why?](https://web.archive.org/web/20120122082554/http://weblogs.java.net/blog/kgh/archive/2004/10/multithreaded_t.html)