# Concurrency loop not updating Label

Tags: javafx

I'm working on this project where I need to make the clock working in real time and keep updating every second in gui. The problem is the clock only updated when the code started. After that it doesnt seems so.

```
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Label jamdisplay ;    

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        ...
        startTime();
    }    
    public void startTime() 
    {
        Runnable task = new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                setTime();
            }
        };
        Thread backgroundThread = new Thread(task);
        backgroundThread.setDaemon(true);
        backgroundThread.start();
    }   
    public void setTime() 
    {
            try
            {
                timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
                time = timeFormat.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
                jamdisplay.setText(time);
                System.out.println(jamdisplay.getText());
         
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}
```

This is not all of the code, I shortened is cos it's too long. `jamdisplay` is the label where I replaced it text with  the time that is not updating. This is my 2nd week of learning how to code, thank you.

Comment: you _must not_ sleep the javafx application thread - and you don't, as I see on second read .. it's the invers: you __must not__ change a node off the fx thread. Next learn item: how to use fx concurrency support :) When stuck on a concrete problem, provide a [mcve] demonstrating what's not working as expected. Aside: don't use the old Date/Calendar classes, instead use LocalDate/Time.

Comment: You should use `Task` for concurency issues in javafx. https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html

Comment: @kleopatra So, I cant change a node of another thread ? how can the `jamdisplay.setText(time);` working **only**  **once** once the code started to run ? Is it because of the initialize ? If so, the only way to get it works correctly is by creating a new node inside the thread, did I get it right ? Much thanks, appreciate so much !

Comment: @Alex I tried, the same problem happened. I think I did something wrong that unrelated to class used...

Comment: repeating: learn about concurrency support in javafx - there are tons of examples/tutorials to study :)

Comment: See if some of the ideas from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50626831/how-to-set-up-two-timelines-to-one-app/50627639#50627639) can help.